# Postman POST Doesn't Pass Parameters

Tags: asp.net, postman

When I try to do a simple POST using Postman, the value of the body of my ASP.NET resource/model object is null when using [FromBody]. For example, I set my parameters in the Body section of postman and call this simple url via postman using POST: http://example.net/api/product.  When I break in my controller, the value of my model parameter is null.

Why don't my parameters translate into a valid resource body?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my controller was set up correctly, but I had not properly set up Postman. To send data for a POST from Postman to an ASP.NET controller, you must go to the Body tab in Postman and 
1) enter the parameters
2) select the "x-www-form-urlencoded" radio button
3) make sure that you don't have and Accept-Type set on the Headers tab.  This is important as it will override the "x-www-form-urlencoded" Accept-Type and will cause your model to not be translated correctly in your ASP.NET controller.  In my example, I had left this set to Accept-Type = application/json and this mistake caused my model to not be translated.

With this properly set up, my controller was able to properly translate my POST data into my model.